# how to add footer to html pages from site.master page

Tags: html, asp.net

I have footer section added in the site.master (aspx) page so all my aspx pages will have the same footer.
However, my site contains some html pages as well. I have to manually copy the html/bootstrap code from the footer section and paste it in all the html pages. Whenever I make a small change to the footer, i have to repeat the same across all HTML pages.  Is there a way to simplify this process instead of having to do this manually

THank you

Comment: Why not make the footer a User Control?

Comment: could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can create footer.html and use iframe in your main html pages; as well as in your master page. For every modification you will need to modify footer.html

```
<body>
     Content.
     <iframe src="footer.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use footerContent

```
<div id="footerContent" style="text-align:center">
     <b>Powered by ASP.NET! </b>
</div>
```

Comment: how is this is going to help me solve my issue here? what do you mean by footercoent here.  I have footer specified in site.master page for e.g. <div class=footerclassid"> copyright text and other footer specific html with styling goes here </div>  I have to copy this section and paste it in every html page that I am trying to find a better solution.

Comment: iframe didn't work properly,  the footer is showing to 50% of width of the page.